# Docker Node JS set env

Tags: node.js, docker, environment-variables

How to set node ENV `process.env.mysql-host` with `docker run`?

Can i somehow do like this? `docker run --mysql-host:127.0.0.1 -p 80:80 -d myApp`

I am using `FROM node:onbuild` as image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node's process.env is an object containing the user environment.  Docker's CLI allows you to set the environment variable for the container using the -e or --env options.

You can run

```
docker run --env mysql_host=127.0.0.1 -p 80:80 -d myApp
```

To pass the mysql_host into the container.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know much about node, but I think you just need to do:

```
docker run -e mysql-host=127.0.0.1 -p 80:80 -d myApp
```

Note that this will look for mysql-host in the same container, *not* on the host, if that's what you're expecting. I think what you really want to do is:

```
$ docker run -d --name db mysql
...
$ docker run -d --link db:mysql-host -p 80:80 -d myApp
```

Which will run the myApp container linked to the db container and resolvable as "mysql-host" inside the myApp container with no need for environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

you could also set node ENV `process.env.mysql-host` inside your `dockerfile`

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /home/app

ADD . /home/app

ENV PORT 3000 
ENV mysql-host 127.0.0.1

EXPOSE 3000
```